# Should I add a "common-sense" warning to an old, good answer?

Tags: discussion, edits, old-answers

Context is everything, so here's the question I'm talking about: [Maven is not working in Java 8 when JavaDoc tags are incomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15886209/maven-is-not-working-in-java-8-when-javadoc-tags-are-incomplete)

The top answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/16743137/1180785 is a perfect answer to the question as asked, and the question is perfectly reasonable. However, a colleague of mine today encountered the same errors as the OP, and found himself on that answer. He saw "You need to turn this off for Java 8 as specified in this thread", and added the proposed code immediately.

The issue here is that the errors are due to a linter which was added in Java 8 (not present in Java 7, which he was migrating code from), and the solution in that thread is to **disable the linter** to fix the errors. Looking at the question, this is perfectly reasonable: the OP is aware of the issues and is looking for a way to get a massive codebase compiling before he attempts to fix the mountain of new issues which have appeared. However, in my colleague's case, there were only a handful of issues identified and the correct approach was to fix them immediately.

It's made me worry about how many other places this could be happening (from the up-votes, maybe 190 other places?), and I'd like to edit in a warning to the question (something along the lines of "The best option is to fix the issues in your JavaDoc, but if there are too many then..."), but it seems superfluous from the context of the question (also who am I to claim a "best" solution attributed to somebody else's answer?)

It feels as though this must have been encountered before, so I expect the community already has a convention for dealing with this sort of thing, but I can't find anything on Meta (most questions seem to be about updating questions with new technologies rather than tangentially-related warnings).

What should I do?

Answer (score 4):

**Don't edit a warning into someone's answer**

The proposed edit to that answer is rather drastic, so it would more than likely be denied. You can always in a comment ask the author to edit that in to their answer as an option, but this is dependent on them being attentive or willing.

**Leave a comment detailing your concerns with the solution**

Your best bet is to leave a detailed comment, or even two comments, outlining the reasons why the answer *may* not be a solution to all cases of that error; at the same time including a suggested solution in the case where it is not a solution.

**Leave an answer if the comment is too lengthy**

The kind of ironic part here is that [this was already done](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34809831/1026459) in an answer. It is so far down the page, perhaps you missed it.

> I don't think just turning off DocLint is a good solution, at least not long term. It is good that Javadoc has become a bit more strict so the right way to fix the build problem is to **fix the underlying problem**.

So if you feel so strongly I would suggest also upvoting this answer, adding a supportive comment to it stating your agreement with the premise, and if you were really behind the idea, place a bounty on it to reward it.

Comment: I did indeed miss that answer (after looking down at the next couple and seeing nothing but minor variants on the main answer I somewhat lost faith). I've up-voted it and added a comment to the main answer which will hopefully direct at least some future visitors the right way… I don't expect it to make much difference though; a developer-in-a-hurry will already have an answer by that point, so why keep reading?

Comment: @Dave - Yeah, that is true. However, your comment and concern mostly applies to the thorough developer, so at least some group of users will benefit from the added comment and attention to not turning that feature off.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I'd just tack on a comment to the existing answer, but I could see adding an answer that relates your extra information, prefaced with "Building on XYZ's answer, but taking Java 8 changes into account, ..."

I'm always thankful when someone chimes in adding corner cases or scenarios where they had to slightly adapt an existing answer.

The reality is, you can't fix every outdated answer out there. Your best bet is to choose one that's very highly ranked, that many dups/other answers link to in the hopes of maximizing that your audience coverage.

**EDIT 1**

I guess the question to ask is:  do I comment, edit, or answer?

I'd argue that editing is rarely a solution. Perhaps in CW's, but not in someone's answer. Edits (in my mind) are for typos and minor fixes to syntax/spelling.

Does the information that you're adding have enough meat to stand on its own as an answer? Are you adding sufficiently to someone else's answer to merit another answer? If so, fire away.

If not, I'd think a comment is fine. Perhaps **throw in some bold** to draw attention to it?

Comment: It's not that it's an outdated answer (Java 8 is still the most up-to-date version, and the issue appears when updating from 7 to 8). It's just that it didn't include a warning that the solution isn't actually the best thing to do (because the OP clearly already knew that).